# Floating Point Numbers Do Not Match In Aggregation

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have this sample test collection documents:

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : 1.0,
    "value" : 10.7
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : 2.0,
    "value" : 10.8
}

/* 3 */
{
    "_id" : 3.0,
    "value" : 10.7
}
```

So when I am using $addFields in aggregation pipeline to add new "result" field in document using query:

```
db.test.aggregate([{$addFields:{result:{ $add : ["$value",  .10]}}}]);
```

It gives below result:

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : 1.0,
    "value" : 10.7,
    "result" : 10.8
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : 2.0,
    "value" : 10.8,
    "result" : 10.9
}

/* 3 */
{
    "_id" : 3.0,
    "value" : 10.7,
    "result" : 10.8
}
```

Now I wanted to perform comparison with this newly added field using mongo query:

```
db.test.aggregate([
  {$addFields:{result:{ $add : ["$value",  .10]}}}, 
  { $match : { result : { $eq : 10.8}}}
]);
```

What I see is that above query is correct, but not sure why it return no documents matched?

Am I doing anything wrong here?

Answer (score 3):

The default (and currently, only) native numeric type in JavaScript is a double precision floating point [Number](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number). As noted in other discussion on this question, binary floating point arithmetic is subject to rounding error because some decimal fractions [cannot be represented exactly in binary floating point](http://www.theregister.co.uk/2006/08/12/floating_point_approximation/). A common workaround for this is a data model approach [using a Scale Factor](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/model-monetary-data/#using-a-scale-factor) to avoid storing fractional values.

However, if you are using MongoDB 3.4+ there is a native [Decimal BSON type](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/model-monetary-data/#numeric-decimal) you can use for precision when working with floating point or monetary values. This implements the [IEEE 754 Decimal 128 floating-point format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal128_floating-point_format) which supports exact decimal representation including arithmetic manipulation through MongoDB's aggregation pipeline.

The `mongo` shell includes a `NumberDecimal` helper for passing decimal values through to aggregation queries or CRUD commands.

Setting up some example data:

```
db.test.insert([
    { "_id" : 1.0, "value" : NumberDecimal(10.7) },
    { "_id" : 2.0, "value" : NumberDecimal(10.8) }
])
```

... and using aggregation to compare against the original value and an incremented result:

```
db.test.aggregate([
    { $addFields: {
        "result"  : { "$add": [ "$value",  NumberDecimal(0.10) ] },
    }},

    // Compare value and result against expected value of 10.8
    { $addFields: {
        "matches_value":   { $eq: ["$value",  NumberDecimal(10.8)] },
        "matches_result":  { $eq: ["$result", NumberDecimal(10.8)] }
    }},
])
```

The decimal type correctly maintains precision and can be used for exact matches. Sample output of this aggregation:

```
{
  "result": [
    {
      "_id": 1,
      "value": NumberDecimal("10.7000000000000"),
      "result": NumberDecimal("10.800000000000000"),
      "matches_value": false,
      "matches_result": true
    },
    {
      "_id": 2,
      "value": NumberDecimal("10.8000000000000"),
      "result": NumberDecimal("10.900000000000000"),
      "matches_value": true,
      "matches_result": false
    }
  ],
  "ok": 1
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are not really telling the whole truth in your question. If I take the initial `"value"` fields and add them with `0.1` then the result is exactly what I expect:

So insert the documents:

```
db.numbers.insert([
  { "_id" : 1.0, "value" : 10.7  },
  { "_id" : 2.0, "value" : 10.8  },
  { "_id" : 3.0, "value" : 10.7  }
])
```

Then run the same initial aggregation statement:

```
db.numbers.aggregate([
  { "$addFields":{
    "result": { "$add": [ "$value",  0.10 ] }
  }}
]);
```

The result:

```
{ "_id" : 1, "value" : 10.7, "result" : 10.799999999999999 }
{ "_id" : 2, "value" : 10.8, "result" : 10.9 }
{ "_id" : 3, "value" : 10.7, "result" : 10.799999999999999 }
```

Welcome to computer science. This is floating point math, and it simply always has rounding error. For the full read, get into this:

[What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html).

We can correct this simply by not using fractional numbers and rounding out to factored integers. In this case **x10**:

```
db.numbers.aggregate([
  { "$addFields": {
    "result": {
      "$divide": [
        { "$add": [
          { "$multiply": [ "$value", 10 ] },
          1
        ]},
        10
      ]
    }
  }}
])
```

Where the `"result"` comes out like this:

```
{ "_id" : 1, "value" : 10.7, "result" : 10.8 }
{ "_id" : 2, "value" : 10.8, "result" : 10.9 }
{ "_id" : 3, "value" : 10.7, "result" : 10.8 }
```

And with the final [`$match`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) only on the requested value:

```
db.numbers.aggregate([
  { "$addFields": {
    "result": {
      "$divide": [
        { "$add": [
          { "$multiply": [ "$value", 10 ] },
          1
        ]},
        10
      ]
    }
  }},
  { "$match": { "result": 10.8 } }
])
```

The correct result

```
{ "_id" : 1, "value" : 10.7, "result" : 10.8 }
{ "_id" : 3, "value" : 10.7, "result" : 10.8 }
```

Comment: Thanks Neil for your response, but I posted correct documents present in test collection and their mongo query results.                                                Your workaround did work, but especially it is not useful for constructing mongo arithmetic expression when trying out different decimal numbers.

Comment: @SagarRathod Yes it does work. They are floating point numbers and this is how you deal with them. Follow my example **exactly**. I'm using the same data you posted.

Comment: @SagarRathod I see your confusion now. You are running this in Robomongo ( Robo 3T) as should have been evidenced by how you present the results in your question. It's bugged, and not displaying the floating point numbers correctly. If you run using the plain [`mongo`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongo/#bin.mongo) shell included with the general distribution, then you see the same output as I have posted. Nonetheless the corrected aggregation statement selects the correct data even in Robo 3T.

Comment: @SagarRathod You also need to understand, it's not a MongoDB bug nor a workaround. It's actually how you are "supposed" to deal with floating point numbers. As is explained in depth in the famous article included in the link within the answer.

Comment: @SagarRathod Just for reference I raised the Bug with Robo 3T https://github.com/Studio3T/robomongo/issues/1393 . But again, this is normal behavior for MongoDB. If you are going to use floating point numbers then you should be factoring out to integers just as I am showing. It's common practice